# wanna finish this its just for fun but its bugging me as hell ... its from a tutorial but I seem to make a mistake somewhere

Tags: c++

it seems that I have made a mistake somewhere and I cant seem to find the problem ... ive searched trough the whole code ... rewrote some of it again ... still no results ... it wants me to make the function-definition somewhere after '{' ... so the full error is "a function-definition is not allowed before "{"token."
    the second problem is the ending token(bracket) if I can call it that ... it wants me to have one at the end but I cant seem to fix that thing (expected "}" at end input.)
    Please give me a solution cuz its bugging me a lot and ive tried for hours now.
the problem isnt that ive done some of it and it will be a waste to delete most of the code but I just want to finish it ... im using it as time killer but still its frustrating ... so if someone can help please do I would appreciate it because even though its just to kill time its still frustrating.
So guys have fun finding the error and good luck ... ill do my best as well and if I find it I will delete the post!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int row,column;

main()

{

    int choice;

    char board[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};

    char turn = 'X';

void display_board()

{
    system("cls");  
    cout<<"\t\t  T i c k    C r o s s   G a m e"<<endl;
    cout<<" Player - 1 [X] \n Player - 2 [0]";
    cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

    cout<<"\t\t _____ _____ _____ \n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[0][0]<<"  |  "<<board[0][1]<<"  |  "<<board[0][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";  
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<<"  |  "<<board[1][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<<"  |  "<<board[2][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";

        cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 1 [X] turn:";
        cin>>choice;
                switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    board[0][0] = 'X';
                    break;              
                case 2:
                    board[0][1] = 'X';
                    break;                  
                case 3:
                    board[0][2] = 'X';
                    break;              
                case 4:
                    board[1][0] = 'X';  
                    break;
                case 5:
                    board[1][1] = 'X';  
                    break;
                case 6:
                    board[1][2] = 'X';  
                    break;
                case 7:
                    board[2][0] = 'X';  
                    break;              
                case 8:
                    board[2][1] = 'X';  
                    break;
                case 9:
                    board[2][2] = 'X';  
                    break;

                default:
                    cout<<"Invalid Choice"<<endl;
                    break;                          
                }
            }
void player_turn ()

    int choice;
            if(turn =='X')
            cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 1 [x] turn:";

            if(turn == '0')
            cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 2 [0]turn:";

            cin>>choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 1: row =0; column =0; break;
            case 2: row =0; column =1; break;
            case 3: row =0; column =2; break;
            case 4: row =1; column =0; break;
            case 5: row =1; column =1; break;
            case 6: row =1; column =2; break;
            case 7: row =2; column =0; break;
            case 8: row =2; column =1; break;
            case 9: row =2; column =2; break;

                default:
                    cout<<"Invalid Choice\n";
                    break;
        }
        if(turn == 'X')
        {
            board[row][column]= 'X';
            turn ='0';
        }
        else if(turn == '0')
        {
            board[row][column]= '0';
            turn ='X';
        }       
}
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t  T i c k    C r o s s   G a m e"<<endl;
    cout<<" Player - 1 [X] \n Player - 2 [0]";

    cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;
    main()
{   
    while(true)
    {
    display_board();
    player_turn [0];    
    }   
    int choice;
    char board[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};
    char turn (0);

    cout<<"\t\t _____ _____ _____ \n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[0][0]<<"  |  "<<board[0][1]<<"  |  "<<board[0][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";  
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<<"  |  "<<board[1][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<<"  |  "<<board[2][2]<<"  |\n";
    cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";

    cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 2 [0] turn:";
        cin>>choice;
            switch(choice)
            {
                    case 1:
                    board[0][0] = '0';
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    board[0][1] = '0';
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    board[0][2] = '0';
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    board[1][0] = '0';  
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    board[1][1] = '0';  
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    board[1][2] = '0';  
                    break;
                    case 7:
                    board[2][0] = '0';  
                    break;
                    case 8:
                    board[2][1] = '0';  
                    break;
                    case 9:
                    board[2][2] = '0';  
                    break;

                    default:
                    cout<<"Invalid Choice"<<endl;
                    break;
  }
```

}

Comment: It's hard to know where to begin fixing this code. I'd start with properly indenting the code so it matches the braces. You will notice that many of your braces aren't matched. In addition, you have what looks like 2 different main functions which is fundamentally incorrect. Fixing these concerns won't have your code working, but it will be a necessary start.

Comment: You missing a lot of curly braces (`{}`) in your code. You are trying to define `main()` twice (it has to be `int main()` btw). Basically, you made the classic mistake of "writing too much code in one go". When you write code, you should *never* write more than few lines without testing if it works in between. You you strat with writing `int main()` with some print and see if it works. Then you add a bit of logic and see if that works, in a couple of increments you have working code and you know it's working (or if you hit an error, you can go back and see what changed since last edit).

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to debug small programs: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You could simplify your code with a little more math: `row = (cell / 3) - 1; column = (cell % 3) - 1; board[row][column] = 'X';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, your code is working.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int row,column;

    int choice;

    char board[3][3] = {{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};

    char turn = 'X';


    void display_board()
    {
        system("clear");
        cout<<"\t\t  T i c k    C r o s s   G a m e"<<endl;
        cout<<" Player - 1 [X] \n Player - 2 [0]";
        cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

        cout<<"\t\t _____ _____ _____ \n";
        cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[0][0]<<"  |  "<<board[0][1]<<"  |  "<<board[0][2]<<"  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<<"  |  "<<board[1][2]<<"  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|     |     |     |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<<"  |  "<<board[2][2]<<"  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|_____|_____|_____|\n";

    }

    void player_turn ()
    {
        if(turn =='X')
            cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 1 [x] turn:";

        if(turn == '0')
            cout<<"\n\tPlayer - 2 [0]turn:";

        cin>>choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: row =0; column =0; break;
            case 2: row =0; column =1; break;
            case 3: row =0; column =2; break;
            case 4: row =1; column =0; break;
            case 5: row =1; column =1; break;
            case 6: row =1; column =2; break;
            case 7: row =2; column =0; break;
            case 8: row =2; column =1; break;
            case 9: row =2; column =2; break;

            default:
                cout<<"Invalid Choice\n";
                break;
        }

        if(turn == 'X')
        {
            board[row][column]= 'X';
            turn ='0';
        }
        else
        {
            if(turn == '0')
            {
                board[row][column]= '0';
                turn ='X';
            }
        }

        cout<<"\t\t\t\t  T i c k    C r o s s   G a m e"<<endl;
        cout<<" Player - 1 [X] \n Player - 2 [0]";

        cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;

    }

    int main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            display_board();
            player_turn();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

You need to learn how to properly indent and space your code, in order to it be more readable.

Also, you will need to create some bool variable, like your board[3][3], to check if the position chose by the player already had been chose before.

And you will need to create some if statements to check a victory condition, otherwise the game will never end.